# Interface variable turns null

Tags: java, android

So, I know it's no good practice, but I have a class extending ArrayList.
I do this to have an ArrayList which is able to tell an other Components (Adapters etc) that its data has changed.

Like this:

```
public class ListenableArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements Listenable<T>{
    private ListListener<T> listener;

    @Override
    public void setListener(ListListener<T> listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T object){
        boolean b = super.add(object);
        if (listener != null){
            listener.onChange();
        } else{
           Log.d("ListListener", "Listener is null");  
        }

        return b;
    }
        //I also overwrite remove(Object object) and remove(int index) on the same way
}

public interface Listenable<T> {
    void setListener(ListListener<T> listener);
}

public interface ListListener<T> {
    void onChange();
}
```

I call add every time a new BluetoothDevice is found in my area (BroadcastReceiver), and I get my ListenableArrayList in an RecyclerView.Adapter.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements ListListener{

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context){
        ....
        this.deviceList = MyApp.getInstance().getManager().getDeviceList;

        this.deviceList.setListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onChange() {
        deviceList = MyApp.getInstance().getManager().getDeviceList();

        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("ListListener", "adapter listener listened");
    }
}
```

While debugging I found that on the first add onChange is called, after that my listener is null. I don't know what I did wrong :/

Comment: Aside: you should also notify from addAll, removeAll and clear.

Comment: If what you say is happening, it's not due to the code you've shown here.  Have you tried putting a watchpoint on the `listener` variable?

Comment: @AndyTurner did this, thanks. :)

Comment: @DavidWallace trying this now - didn't know about this debugging function ..

Comment: Does your method MyApp.getInstance().getManager().getDeviceList(); always return a new List-object or always the same? Because you set your class attribute deviceList in your onChange-Method again without setting up a listener.

Comment: Another aside: you are presumably having to implement the conditional notify logic in a number of places. Instead of a null listener, consider using the Null Object pattern: implement a listener which logs the message when onChange is called. Use this by default, and whenever somebody sets the listener to null. This removes the need to handle null and non-null cases differently.

Comment: ... why trying to reinvent the wheel: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList.html

Comment: @Christopher MyApp.getInstance().getManager().getDeviceList(); returns always the same List..

Comment: Oh, and you'd need to notify from set too, ofc, and insert. And subList. In fact, the fact that you need to override subList means that your inheritance-based approach doesn't work, at least not robustly, since you'd need to return a subList which notifies too. I would use composition instead, which would allow you to implement subList correctly, and remove the fragility of depending on the base class.

Comment: Back to the drawing board it is! I obviously need to change my list class. Thanks a lot. :)